# Configure SElinux to allow a Linux user to run no more than one command from /usr/bin

Tags: selinux

Does anyone have any tips for configuring SELinux to allow a Linux user to run no more than one command from /usr/bin?

For example, how to configure SELinux so that Linux user, joe, can execute only the command /usr/bin/ac and no other command from /usr/bin?

So Linux user joe should be prevented from executing everything under /usr/bin except /usr/bin/ac.  How to do that?

I appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you expect this only for ssh users, you might go for easy solution by creating a shell wrapper and doing a normal policy with transition. Then set this wrapper as a shell for all users you want to constraint. If this should be for local users, you need SELinux roles/users, best resource would be SELinux Cookbook, I have never done that.

The former is just a normal policy with executable transition, I believe.